# Unauthorized requests to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I developed an open source library and hosted its assets on Amazon S3 (CSS, JS), these files were used in demo via URLs like: `http://my_bucket_name.s3.amazonaws.com/some-file.js` (my bad, I know).  Without my permission, some websites started hot-linking these files.

It was fine for a while, but recently a few large NSFW sites hot-linked it and I get tens of millions GET requests in a month. So I deleted/moved these files, but I still get a lot of GET requests that return 403 errors, and Amazon bills them as a valid requests (see [Charge Details section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RequesterPaysBuckets.html#ChargeDetails)).

- I tried contacting sites that hotlinked my library, but never got any reply.
- I'm worried that if I delete the bucket "my_bucket_name", someone else might create it with the same name and hotlink malicious JS files.

What should I do to avoid getting billed for error requests that I don't make?

Comment: Why did you enable requester pay ? Maybe you could turn that bucket to private using bucket policy. / an advice always use proxy front s3 so you can manage your requesters and block bad ones.

Comment: Are you sure that modifying bucket policy would make any difference? All files in a bucket are already private or deleted and no one can access them. Yea, I know that I should've used proxy in front of s3, but I didn't... Thank you for reply.

Comment: Just nuke the whole bucket. That'll put a stop to it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, as I originally posted - if I delete the bucket, someone else might create it with the same name and hotlink malicious JS files, I don't want that.

Comment: Once you delete the bucket it's not your problem any more. S3 will send 404 responses and people will stop using it, the problem will go away.

Comment: And you aren't responsible for maintaining other people's web sites.

Comment: Yea it seems not working. Maybe you should delete bucket , announce for reqesters. https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=58436

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Delete the bucket
- or disable static website access to the bucket and keep the bucket. Then use a new bucket.

You might want to add a policy to this bucket to restrict the access to the bucket, e.g. [Restricting Access to a Specific HTTP Referrer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4)